# Knockoutjs with punches unable to place binding in style attribute

Tags: javascript, html, css, knockout.js

I'm using KnockoutJS with the punches plugin so I can bind values using curly braces. I'm fairly new to knockoutjs so my knowledge on the subject is limited.

All is working well except when I try to bind into the style attribute of an element.

Here is a simple JS fiddle demonstrating the issue.

https://jsfiddle.net/brz3b0wv/4/

In a runnable stack snippet (note that it logs an error in your console):

```js
ko.punches.enableAll();

//Test function to calculate some width
ko.filters.getWidth = function (value) {
    return value * 0.5;
};

ko.filters.getClass = function(value) {
 return value;
}

ko.applyBindings({
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://mbest.github.io/knockout.punches/knockout.punches.js"></script>
<h1>Testing Knockout Punches</h1>

<!-- This works -->
Width: {{ 500 | getWidth }} 
<br>
Class: {{ 'blue' | getClass }}

<!-- Binding into eg. class works. Style however does not -->
<div class="{{ 'blue' | getClass }}" style="width: {{ 1000 | getWidth }}px">
</div>
```

The console returns the following error. While the filter IS defined

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "style: function (){return ""+"width: "+ko.unwrap( 1000 | getWidth)+"px" }" Message: getWidth is not defined
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug/limitation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fiddled around with the Punches plugin and found three ways to "fix" your example. To me, fix 1 feels like it matches the plugin's goals the best... It's also similar to what's in the docs. Fix 2 feels weird... Fix 3 might be a bit too similar to regular knockout syntax to bring you any added benefits.

I haven't used this plugin before, so it might be worth it to wait for an answer from somebody with more experience as well.. (I believe the creator of the plug in also visits stack overflow quite regularly :) )

### Fix 1:

- Enable the custom filtering syntax for the `style.width` binding

  ```
  ko.punches.textFilter.enableForBinding('style.width');
  ```
- namespace your attribute like so:

  ```
  style.width="{{ ... }}"
  ```
- Take care of the "px" suffix in an `append` filter

  ```
  ko.filters.append = (str1, str2) => str1 + str2;
  ```

  (or even `ko.filters.px = str => str + 'px'`)
- Create the width string within the curly braces: `{{ 1000 | getWidth | append:'px' }}`

```js
ko.punches.enableAll();
ko.punches.textFilter.enableForBinding('style.width');

//Test function to calculate some width
ko.filters.getWidth = function (value) {
    return value * 0.5;
};

ko.filters.append = function(v1, v2) {
 return v1 + v2;
}

ko.filters.getClass = function(value) {
 return value;
}

ko.applyBindings({});
```

```css
.blue { background: blue; height: 100px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://mbest.github.io/knockout.punches/knockout.punches.js"></script>

<div class="{{ 'blue' | getClass }}" style.width="{{500 | getWidth | append:'px'}}">
</div>
```

### Fix 2:

- Enable the custom filtering syntax for the `style` binding

  ```
  ko.punches.textFilter.enableForBinding('style');
  ```
- Bring all of the values between the curly braces and use the `append` filter described in *Fix 1*
- Add an additional filter to wrap in an object and target "width"

  ```
  style="{{ 500 | getWidth | append:'px' | objWrap:'width' }}"
  ```

```js
ko.punches.enableAll();
ko.punches.textFilter.enableForBinding('style');

//Test function to calculate some width
ko.filters.getWidth = function (value) {
    return value * 0.5;
};

ko.filters.append = function(v1, v2) {
 return v1 + v2;
}

ko.filters.objWrap = function(v, k) {
 var obj = {};
  obj[k] = v;
  return obj;
}

ko.filters.getClass = function(value) {
 return value;
}

ko.applyBindings({});
```

```css
.blue { background: blue; height: 100px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://mbest.github.io/knockout.punches/knockout.punches.js"></script>

<div class="{{ 'blue' | getClass }}" style="{{ 500 | getWidth | append:'px' | objWrap:'width' }}">
</div>
```

### Fix 3:

- Use the regular `data-bind` attribute with the name spaced `style.width` similar to fix 1

```js
ko.punches.enableAll();
ko.punches.textFilter.enableForBinding('style.width')

//Test function to calculate some width
ko.filters.getWidth = function (value) {
    return value * 0.5;
};

ko.filters.append = function(v1, v2) {
 return v1 + v2;
}

ko.filters.getClass = function(value) {
 return value;
}

ko.applyBindings({});
```

```css
.blue { background: blue; height: 100px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://mbest.github.io/knockout.punches/knockout.punches.js"></script>

<div class="{{ 'blue' | getClass }}" data-bind="style.width: 500 | getWidth | append:'px'">
</div>
```

Comment: This is fantastic. Solution #1 also immediately taught me some other tricks which helped me solve some other issues I was facing. Thank you kindly!